# Get results onClick event and keep previous request parameter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 bootstrap dropdown menus in order to filter the database results each time and I want on a click event to run the Ajax call. At the current time everything works fine, except that every time I can only get the result for each one of the drop downs and not a combination of all 3. I can not figure a solution because with the ajax call I cannot get the url parameters that I need for my next call. I'm open to listen a better way of doing that if is needed.

Some code:(Notice: I use Laravel framework)

```
<div class="col-lg-5">
  <div class="btn-group dropup">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Sort By Location</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-sm" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="{{ route('properties') }}" data-location="">ALL</a></li>
        @foreach ($allLocations as $location)
           <li><a href="{{ route('properties') }}<?= $location->location_id ?>" data-location="<?= $location->location_id ?>">{{$location->name}}</a></li>
        @endforeach
      </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group dropup">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm ">Sort By Agent</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-sm" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
         <li><a href="{{ route('properties') }}" data-agent="">ALL</a></li>
         @foreach ($allAgents as $agent)
           <li><a href="{{ route('properties') }}<?= $agent->person_id ?>" data-agent="<?= $agent->person_id ?>">{{$agent->lastname.' '.$agent->firstname}}</a></li>
         @endforeach
      </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group dropup">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm ownerf" id="ownerFilter">Sort By Owner</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-sm" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
         <li><a href="{{ route('properties') }}" data-owner="">ALL</a></li>
         @foreach ($allOwners as $owner)
           <li><a href="{{ route('properties') }}<?= $owner->person_id ?>" data-ownername="<?= $owner->lastname ?>" data-owner="<?= $owner->person_id ?>">{{$owner->lastname.' '.$owner->firstname}}</a></li>
         @endforeach
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

and some jQuery:

```
function updateProperties(url){
$.get(url)
        .done(function(result){  
        $data = $(result); 
        var rows =  $data.find("#propertyResults > *"); 
        $('#propertyResults').fadeOut().html(rows).fadeIn();
        var pages =  $data.find("#propertyPages > *"); 
        $('#propertyPages').empty().html(pages).fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to acheive is using multiple search filters. Why dont you use `checkboxes` or `multi-select dropdown`, if you need the results of all the three combinations.

**Example:**

If there are three options. Whenever a user selects an option, using jquery you can get the values of the selected options

Here is the sample jquery snippet

```
$('select#my_multiselect').val()
```

This will **return an array of selected values**. Send it as a json to the server and get back the results.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, i thought to do it in that way or by using a form, but i want to avoid to submit the form. I need when the user clicks, for example, the first filter, to apply the ajax results and then, when clicks the second or the third to combine it with the previous filter. Is that a bad way to do such things? what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: No.. what you are thinking is absoluely correct. You dont have to submit the form, on the click on the options you can get the values of the selected option  and run the ajax call